# Query muito demorada dependendo do ID da consulta

Tags: postgresql

Olá,

Tenho uma query razoavelmente grande que está sendo executada no banco, segue.

```
SELECT "p"."id", "fr"."apelido", "fr"."compra_minima", "fr"."desconto", "fr"."aplicavel_todocarrinho"
FROM "basket" "b"
JOIN "produtos" "p" ON "p"."id" = "b"."id_produto"
LEFT JOIN "produtos_multicategoria" "pm" ON "pm"."id_produto" = "p"."id"
LEFT JOIN "frete_regrapromocao_categorias" "frc" ON "frc"."id_cateprod" IN (p.id_categoria, pm.id_categoria_1, pm.id_categoria_2,pm.id_categoria_3, pm.id_categoria_4, pm.id_categoria_5)
LEFT JOIN "frete_regrapromocao_fabricante" "frf" ON "frf"."id_fabricante" = "p"."id_fabricante"
JOIN "frete_regrapromocao" "fr" ON (("fr"."id" = frc.id_regrapromocao) OR ("fr"."id" = frf.id_regrapromocao))
JOIN "frete_regrapromocao_regiao" "frr" ON "frr"."id_regrapromocao" = "fr"."id"
LEFT JOIN "produtos_fretegratis" "pf" ON "pf"."id_produto" = "p"."id"
WHERE "b"."reve_cod" = '1748'
AND "p"."id" = '673884'
AND "fr"."id_formaentrega" = '5408'
AND "fr"."cupom" = 'F'
AND "fr"."status" = 'T'
AND "frr"."esta_cod" = 'PR'
AND "frr"."id_capital" = 'S'
AND "fr"."varejo" = 'T'
AND pf.id ISNULL
AND (p.valor_venda * 1) > "fr"."compra_minima"
GROUP BY "p"."id", "fr"."apelido", "fr"."compra_minima", "fr"."desconto", "fr"."aplicavel_todocarrinho"
ORDER BY "fr"."aplicavel_todocarrinho" DESC, "fr"."desconto" DESC
```

O problema acontece quando, na linha 10, o valor do ID da loja é 1748, a query está demorando uns 5 segundos para executar. Eu já testei com lojas com menos registros no banco e lojas com mais registros, mas a query é executada instantaneamente sempre, só nesse caso específico demora tanto.

O banco é Postgre e a query está sendo gerada pelo Query Builder do Codeigniter 3.1. Eu acredito que não seja nenhum erro na query, pois nas outras lojas funciona normalmente.

*A tabela basket precisou ser recuperada à uns dias atrás, não acho que isso esteja causando o problema, mas como não entendo de banco de dados, achei importante mencionar...

Comment: Rode um EXPLAIN ANALYZE. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE. Você também pode ver as dicas em https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: Vou testar. Consegui contornar a situação, mas não achei o problema. Vou rodar um EXPLAIN ANALYZE para ver se descubro.

Comment: Deu certo, consegui achar onde era o problema. Essa loja em específico tinha vários registros na tabela `frete_regrapromocao_categorias`. Obrigado, não conhecia o EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Comment: É fundamental para quem trabalha com PostgreSQL (e também para todos os outros SGBD que o implementam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo você rodar as consultas com o pgAdmin3 ou pgAdmin4 primeiramente, ou mesmo através do psql. Parece que em um banco é rápido e em outro está lento, pode ser algum problema de indexação.

Primeiramente se possível execute um backup da base de dados e a restaure novamente, após rode alguns processos como VACUUM FULL ANALYZE e um REINDEX. Através do pgAdmin3 podemos rodar desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se estes processos de manutenção no resultarem uma melhora, você pode executar um comando para verificar como está sendo feitas as leituras em cada banco:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT...
```

Este comando retorna informações das leituras, índices, custo em milissegundos de cada parte do seu select, etc... Você terá que estudar
No pgAdmin através do comando F7 existe uma análise visual que também pode auxiliar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer dúvida passe a estrutura de criação das tabelas e mais informações da versão do PostgreSQL em que está sendo executada estas bases, assim teremos informações mais precisas.

Comment: Eu tinha conseguido descobrir o problema com o `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, em um pedaço da query uma consulta estava retornando milhares de resultados, daí travava. Mas sua resposta resolveria meu problema. (:

Comment: O EXPLAIN ANALYZE é excelente, ajuda a entender a teoria da QUERY, porém sempre é bom rodar uma manutenção no banco de dados. No arquivo postgresql.conf existe configurações de VACUUM. Eu tive muitas experiencias de lentidão com o PostgreSQL, hoje adoto um padrão de desligar o AUTOVACUUM e fazer um agendamento que roda o VACUUM diariamente de madrugada, você pode considerar alterar a configuração do seu PostgreSQL também.